# Tomcat in Intellij IDEA error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am asked to move the default configuration of my team project from Eclipse to Intellij. I have never do server configuration for tomcat so i am confused to convert the eclipse configuration to Intellij IDEA. I have successfully get page that tomcat server installed for default tomcat, but when i use the team project tomcat configuration i get this error:

```
19-Jul-2017 09:45:38.903 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@50d3c660]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4969)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\PR\tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.37 - Admin Bo\webapps\pr-admin] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:688)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 9 more

    19-Jul-2017 09:45:38.904 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 6 more

    19-Jul-2017 09:45:38.905 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8001]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 11 more

    19-Jul-2017 09:45:38.909 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8000"]
    19-Jul-2017 09:45:38.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
    19-Jul-2017 09:45:38.911 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8000"]
    19-Jul-2017 09:45:38.911 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8000"]
     java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

    19-Jul-2017 09:45:38.913 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStop Error stopping static Resources
     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@50d3c660]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStop(StandardContext.java:4995)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5576)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1012)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1012)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:604)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_stop]) for component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.FileResourceSet@76b0bfab] in state [INITIALIZED]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.stopInternal(StandardRoot.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
        ... 21 more

    19-Jul-2017 09:45:38.918 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy Calling stop() on failed component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@50d3c660] to trigger clean-up did not complete.
     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@50d3c660]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.destroyInternal(StandardContext.java:5655)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1012)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1012)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:604)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_stop]) for component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.FileResourceSet@76b0bfab] in state [INITIALIZED]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.stopInternal(StandardRoot.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
        ... 20 more

    Disconnected from server
```

How to resolve this error? I have googling it for similar problem, it is say have dependencies problem. But i don't know how to check the what jar that have dependencies problem in here. Thank you

Addition:
Here the successful log message from running the server from eclipse IDE:

```
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:pr-admin' did not find a matching property.
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Sep 1 2016 10:01:52 UTC
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.37.0
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\PR\tools\jdk1.8.0\jre
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\PR\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\PR\tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.37
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\PR\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\PR\tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.37
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\PR\workspace
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\PR\tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\endorsed
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Duser.timezone=Asia/Jakarta
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\PR\tools\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\PR\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Sky\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\node_modules\appium;C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\;C:\Android\sdk\tools\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Gradle\gradle-4.0.1\bin;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Users\Sky\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Sky\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\PR\eclipse-jee-neon-1-win32-x86_64;;.
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8000"]
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:13 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1301 ms
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 19, 2017 9:37:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Updated:
Now i can run the server but i have this error in event log:
    Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
                java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
                java.io.EOFException]

Also i get the warning 19-Jul-2017 13:04:49.941 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: Invalid command '' received
19-Jul-2017 13:04:49.941 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: Invalid command 'JRMI' received

Answer (score 1):

- You have probably added something not valid into the lib folder of your server.
- May be the version of your maven dependencies are not supporting your tomcat version.

What you can try is :

1. remove your existing tomcat, if possible
2. remove your project and add your project with a new build
3. add your tomcat server (if possible try to add the same version in eclipse)
4. clean the project and refresh the project
5. go for running or debug mode

Comment: i can the run server now but i get other error (see the update in question).

Comment: Can you tell me the version of your tomcat in ecllipse?

Comment: i use apache-tomcat-8.0.37

Comment: you have installed the same version in intellij also na ...the version in both eclipse and intelij should be same because there are some dependencies which are server version dependent.

Comment: tomcat i use for the eclipse and intellij is both same , but the problem in the eclipse you can setting the configuration with configuration path like in Servers/pr-config, pr-config contain the server.xml, web.xml and others, also the Servers folder contain the httpd-ssl and httpd-vhosts. How to setting the tomcat in intellij IDEA so use that configs? I have try make other apache tomcat server folder and copy manually the configs from Servers folder to copy of tomcat server folder but still fail.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Put the deployment]

Put the deployment into the current project directory or folder all permission

Answer (score 0):

Just you can try to again reconfigure your tomcat .

To configure tomcat in intellij its quite different than that in eclipse

Go to Edit Configuration and complete the configuration as shown in image below

[image]

Comment: Here the project eclipse settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz6IT.png and here the tomcat settings that i have try: http://imgur.com/a/5r07M . And this is the deployment setting http://imgur.com/a/jwOVN.

Comment: Everything seems fine with this try to increase the TIMEOUTS start and stop time may be the server is not getting enough time to load the complete project properly

Comment: How to increase the timeout in intellij? But i still get the errors (in the update of question). Also i still get the  Artifact x:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.

Answer (score 0):

When tomcat is not showing in intellij . Make sure to follow below steps

1} You should Install Tomcat and TomEE Integration plugin.

File –>> Settings –>> Type Plugin –>> Make sure Tomcat and TomEE Integration should be checked. Otherwise, you should install the plugin by clicking Install JetBrains Plugin button.

[image]

2} Make sure to add Deployment related in Edit Configuration for your project

[image]

3} Then start the tomcat.

[image]

Hope it works!